# How to detect outside touch of TextInput In React-native

Tags: react-native

I have created one custom dropdown list View.
From that View users can search as well as select data by clicking on it.
But My Question is if user click on outside space after opening that list view, then it should close automatically like alert, popup.

but currently it's not working as expected.

I have written below code:

{modalVisible ?

```
(
  <View style={styles.emailItem}>
  <ShowCustomDropdown globalsearchdata={globalsearchdata} />
  </View>
) : null}
<View style={styles.textinputstyle}>
   <TextInput
     onTouchStart={()=> setModalVisible(true)}
     onChangeText={handleChange}
     style={styles.searchInput}
     placeholder="Type a message"
     value={search_term}
   />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `onTouchStart` prop, you can use below props in `TextInput`, like:

```js
<TextInput
   onFocus={() => setModalVisible(true) }   //focus received
   onBlur={() => setModalVisible(false) }   //focus lost
   onChangeText={handleChange}
   style={styles.searchInput}
   placeholder="Type a message"
   value={search_term}
/>
```

`onFocus` prop will let you know if `TextInput` is focussed and `onBlur` prop will let you know when you click outside `TextInput` or it isn't focussed.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Yes onBlur works as expected for android but not for ios platform

Comment: I tried it on ios, working fine for me. You can also replace `onBlur` with `onEndEditing` prop then check.